# IntelliJ used methods highlighting problem

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ. So far it worked fine and highlighted every used method in yellow. Never used methods appeared in grey. But now it doesn't work anymore. All methods simply remain grey. Only after I close and reopen IntelliJ it is updated and the ones used are shown in yellow.

How to fix this?

Comment: Please try to run "File | Invalidate Caches". Also please attach idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling your methods at all? Easy check, if they are being used they will appear in yellow. If not, they will appear in grey and be underlined.

Comment: Sure. As I stated above. They only become yellow if i close and restart IntelliJ.